# Recovery of files from dead windows using Ubuntu

Tags: boot, mount, windows, hard-drive

Something happened with my windows 10 computer and it wont start up as it should. To solve this I have gotten myself a Ubuntu Live USB stick and plugged it and managed to start the Ubuntu OS up. So, now when I tried to access the harddrive from the “Files“ dropdown menu it gives the following error message...

```
“Unable to access “1000 GB Volume”

Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/ubuntu/0C1281071280F6CC: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda4" "/media/ubuntu/0C1281071280F6CC"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.“
```

I have at least found out that I might be able to “force“ ubuntu to open the disk, but I do not know how. (Some comands to enter into terminal perhaps?)

My question, how do I get access to my harddrive through Ubuntu so I can save some files from the not functioning computer?

Comment: This is "`exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).`", seems different.

Comment: Newer Ubuntu versions (17.04) will automatically mount as read-only if read-write mounting fails.  It may be worth a try.

Comment: Managed to solve this using a read only command, 
Make a mount point, call it anything you like:
“sudo mkdir /media/2tb“
Mount:
“sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda4 /media/2tb“.
This solved my problem and I managed to access my files.